# $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is injective on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is injective on $[1,\infty)$. I'm having a huge brain-fart... I'm assuming $\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{y}{1+y^2}$, yada yada, $\implies \frac{1}{x}+x=\frac{1}{y}+y$... but I can't get past this step!!!

Answer (score 1):

if $1 \leq x < y,$  then $y-x > 0 $  and $xy - 1 > 0$ and
$$  \frac{x}{1+x^2} - \frac{y}{1 + y^2}  = \frac{(y-x)(xy-1)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)} >0$$